# DataSet Update vs SQL query

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, vb.net

I have a situation where in every minute I need to fetch about 200 records from SQL Server process it and update the status field with 1 for success and unchanged/0 for failure of 200 records and then write back to DB. In this case should I go by .net method of making changes to data table and then at the end of loop call the update method based on the processing status.

Or should I go the direct method of making a loop like this

```
String sql = "update customer set status = 1 where id in ("
while records in dataset
    sql = sql + dataset.getId + ","
end while
and the execute sql;
```

Which method is more efficient? What I actually want to know is that if I make changes to just one column in dataTable and update, in the backend how will that query be executed? Is it just one sql or multiple for each row. If its multiple then should I go by the old sql method or is there some other suggested method.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by process? If that is a change to the data and you are writing back the change to the DB, you might want to consider a trigger.

Comment: @Raj process is something else. i'm not changing any other columns. just suppose I want to check something based on the details fetched by connecting to other server and if its successful I will have to update that row with 1 in the status column. Otherwise no change.

Comment: Your 2nd method will be efficient as it will be executed as a single query. but the yourDataAdapter.Update(datatable) will be executing single row at a time, so 200 queries will be executing (worst case).
but try to have some better solution, like do this at DB level i mean in stored procedure.

Answer (score 1):

Your 2nd method will be efficient as it will be executed as a single query. 
But the yourDataAdapter.Update(datatable) will be executing single row at a time, so 200 queries will be executing (worst case).

check this
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dataadapter.update(v=vs.80).aspx

It says:

`Calls the respective INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE statements for each inserted, updated, or deleted row in the specified DataSet from a DataTable named "Table."`

Note: `for each inserted, updated, or deleted row`

I have tested this dataAdapter.Update 2 years ago, it executes queries row by row.

But try to have this update logic at DB end like...

`update c
set status = 1
from customer as c
inner join yourOtherTable as t on c.id = t.id
where ....`

Answer (score 0):

As long as your object doesn't have hundreds of properties, the difference in performance would be pretty trivial. You'll spend more time writing up the code to use either the DataSet or SQL Query that will interact with your objects than the difference between these methods will likely ever make.

**Edit**

As far as "how it is executed in the back end", RDBMSes will generate an "Execution Plan" for the query it is about to run. It would take the server more time to generate execution plans for 100 different queries than it would take to run the same query (with redundant/useless information) 100 times.

Comment: So what exactly is the suggested method in my case. I want to know how DataTable.update is implemented in backend. When same column in multiple rows are to be updated, is it one query or different one?

Answer (score 0):

The following code will delete records with a 1 in the given field used ("testfield").  If the field you are testing is a date, then the query gets more complex:

```
        Dim MyValue as Byte 
        Dim TableName, FieldName As String

        Dim ConnString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source="c:\mydata\myfile.mdb"
        Dim cn As New OleDbConnection(ConnString)
        cn.Open()

        Dim qry As String
        Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(qry, cn)
        TableName="salary"
        FieldName = "testfield"
        myvalue = 1
        qry = " DELETE from " & TableName & " WHERE ( " & FieldName & " = '" & myvalue & "' )"
        Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(qry, cn)
        recordsadded = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```